# Using NLTK to tokeniz sentences to words using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk

I'm trying to tokenize sentences from a csv file into words but my loop is not jumping to the next sentence its just doing first column. any idea where is the mistake ?
this is how my CSV file look like [image]

```
import re
import string
import pandas as pd
text=pd.read_csv("data.csv")
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
tokenized_docs=[word_tokenize(doc) for doc in text]
x=re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))
tokenized_docs_no_punctuation = []
```

the output I'm getting is like this

[image]

which I expected to do for all sentences as a loop not just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the code to grab the sentences:

```
import re
import string
import pandas as pd
text=pd.read_csv("out157.txt", sep="|")
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
tokenized_docs=[word_tokenize(doc) for doc in text['SENTENCES']]
x=re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation))
tokenized_docs_no_punctuation = []
```